# Why is my base navbar doesn't show the groups that I have at /groups/?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to do a dropdown list in the base navigation bar of the groups that are available inside the /groups/ which is a ListView.

The navigation bar shows the groups only when I am at /groups/ on my website.

in views.py at Groups application

```py
class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group
    context_object_name = 'All_Groups'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.all()
```

in the main templates, base.html

```html
{% for group in All_Groups %}
  <li>
    <a href='{% url "groups:single" slug=group.slug %}' class='my-dropdown-list' style='color: white !important; background-color: inherit !important;'>
        {{group.name}}
    </a>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I expect it to iterate to all the available groups that inherit from the Group class, but it only does that when I am at the directory of Groups.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your view will only work when you go the url that points to that view.

Comment: So, I want to make a navigation bar in the templates folder that is in my main project that takes me to a model named ( Group ) inside an app inside my django project, and I want to iterate through all the groups of my Group model, but it doesn't.
( Idk how to make you understand what is my point )